# How to update a tensor with new value using old value in graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I am pretty new to tensorflow. I would like to use the old value of the tensor to compute the new value. `tf.assign` works only for `tf.Variables`. I am not sure how to achieve this for tensor operation.

The following code is not the actual snippet but the idea is same.

```
data.csv
inp1            inp2
288.15          288.15
289.87912       303.10137
291.60825       318.05275
292.90509       329.26628
294.20194       340.47981
295.75815       353.93605
297.31436       367.39229
298.87057       380.84852
300.42679       394.30476
301.983         407.761
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

inp1 = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1],name="inp1")
inp2 = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1],name="inp2")


# PREVop means previous value of op i.e. op [i-1]

dummy_op = tf.add(inp1, 10)

op = tf.Variable(dummy_op,validate_shape=False,dtype=tf.float32)


# op[i] = (op[i-1]*inp2[i]) + inp1[i]
op = tf.add(tf.multiply(PREVop, inp2), inp1) 

label = tf.placeholder("float", [None,1],name="label")


learning_rate = 1e-2
loss_op = tf.losses.absolute_difference(label, op)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

inp = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
batch_size = 20
training_steps = 100

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print ("Training starts.......")
    for step in range(training_steps):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = len(inp)//batch_size
        for i in range(total_batch):
            idx = np.arange(len(inp))
            np.random.shuffle(idx)
            idx = idx[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
            _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={
            inp1: input1.values[idx] #pandas
            inp2: input2.values[idx] #pandas
            label: target.values[idx], #pandas
            })
```

During training, I am expecting the `op = tf.add(tf.multiply(PREVop, inp2), inp1)` to use the previous value of `op` for each sample.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the value of `op` is always changing, you can use `tf.Variable()` to store its value after every iteration. Here, `tf.Variable()` is initialized with a zero tensor at the start.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

inp1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="inp1")
inp2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="inp2")

PREVop = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 1]), tf.float32)

out = tf.add(tf.multiply(PREVop, inp2), inp1) 
PREVop = tf.assign(PREVop, out)  

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(3):
        res, var = sess.run([out, PREVop], feed_dict={inp1:np.random.rand(2, 1), inp2:np.random.rand(2, 1)})
        print('out operation result: \n{}'.format(res))
        print('PREVop value after assigning: \n{}'.format(var))
        print(20*'-')
```

output:

```
out operation result: 
[[0.86163723]
 [0.7938016 ]]
PREVop value after assigning: 
[[0.86163723]
 [0.7938016 ]]
--------------------
out operation result: 
[[0.5666107]
 [0.9492748]]
PREVop value after assigning: 
[[0.5666107]
 [0.9492748]]
--------------------
out operation result: 
[[0.89638215]
 [0.93310213]]
PREVop value after assigning: 
[[0.89638215]
 [0.93310213]]
--------------------
```

**Update:** So, you want to initialize `PREVop` with `tf.add(inp1, 10)` and then update it with values of `op`, which is `tf.add(tf.multiply(PREVop, inp2), inp1)`. I am adding a way to do this but honestly, I don't like it.

code:

```
batch_size = 2

inp1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1],name="inp1")
inp2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1],name="inp2")

inp3 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="inp3")
PREVop = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch_size, 1]), dtype=tf.float32)
PREVop = tf.assign(PREVop, inp3)

out = tf.add(tf.multiply(PREVop, inp2), inp1)  

inp = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=' ')
x_train = inp.iloc[:,:-1]
training_steps = 100

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    out_res = 0
    for step in range(training_steps):
        total_batch = len(inp)//batch_size
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x = x_train[i*batch_size:min((i+1)*batch_size, len(inp))]

            if step==0 and i==0:
                _, res = sess.run([PREVop, out], feed_dict={inp1: batch_x['inp1'].values.reshape(2, 1), 
                                                            inp2: batch_x['inp2'].values.reshape(2, 1), 
                                                            inp3: batch_x['inp1'].values.reshape(2, 1)+10})   
            else:
                _, res = sess.run([PREVop, out], feed_dict={inp1: batch_x['inp1'].values.reshape(2, 1), 
                                                            inp2: batch_x['inp2'].values.reshape(2, 1), 
                                                            inp3: out_res})
            out_res = res
```

In the above code, `batch_size=2` and I am using a placeholder `inp3` and feed it with the value `inp1+10`, which later on is assigned to the variable `PREVop`. This happened only once at the start, later on `PREVop` is assigned value of `out`(in below code).

Comment: Thanks for the lovely answer. However, when I try to initialize the variable with another tensor am getting some error. I have updated the code snippet for you to reproduce.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: Tell me one thing `initial value of PREVop is 0 ?`

Comment: Nope, initial value of PREVop is from another tensor op like mentioned above.

Comment: It is just numbers, I have provided sample for you.

Comment: these lines: `dummy_op = tf.add(inp1, 10)
op = tf.Variable(dummy_op,validate_shape=False,dtype=tf.float32)
op = tf.add(tf.multiply(PREVop, inp2), inp1)` doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: I have few questions: why you want variable to initialize with an add operation result? As `PREVop` after first iteration is simply op[i-1], then why `dummy_op = tf.add(inp1, 10)`? Add operation will be performed every time you feed a new value of inp1. So, why not initialize variable with a constant like I did in above code. And, why you are using same `op` for both Variable and add operation.

Comment: As I mentioned in the above post, it is not the actual code snippet. I have just removed the previous ops. However, the above code illustrates the similar situation where I have no clue on what to do. I agree, that for the above code snippet we can do like as you mentioned. But the original requirement is to use tensor op as initializer and update it's value with previous computed value for every sample/example. Hope it clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I added a code which you can use to achieve your goal, although I don't like it. See my above code.